# Prevent p:inputNumber adding a decimal point and 2 zeros when not explicitly entered?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, decimal

need help with primefaces input number

```
<p:inputNumber id="test" value="#{test}" thousandSeparator=""/>
```

If my input is like this:

```
100
```

The number field adds a decimal point and 2 zeros like this:

```
100.00
```

Is there a way of restricting this? The user can input decimal points but if the user didn't, there is no need to add a decimal point and the 2 zeros.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `padControl="false"` for inputNumber component.

Comment: For me doesn't work, I need to use this: decimalPlaces="0"

Answer (score -1):

Set `decimalSeparator=""`